# Flip Product image on hover in Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hover

With Woocommerce, I've installed the flip product plugin. It shows me a secondary image bellow the primary. I have tried with some CSS and jQuery code to change opacity on hover, but it doesn't work.

CSS rule:

```
ul.products>.product .mkd-pl-inner .mkd-pl-image .pif-has-gallery .wp-post-image--secondary:hover{opacity:1!important}
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('ul.products li.pif-has-gallery img’ ).hover( function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail').removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass('animated fadeOutUp');
        jQuery(this).find('.secondary-image').removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail').removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass('fadeInDown');
        jQuery(this).find('.secondary-image').removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass('fadeOutUp');
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the website: https://goldandroses.com/shop/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

jQuery:

```
jQuery(".pif-has-gallery").on('mouseenter', function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.wp-post-image').css('opacity','1');
});​
jQuery(".pif-has-gallery").on('mouseleave', function () {
     jQuery(this).find('.wp-post-image').css('opacity','0');
});​
```

CSS:

```
.pif-has-gallery:hover .wp-post-image {
    opacity: 1!important;
}
```

**Please see screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: It gives me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Updated my answer, Please try it now.

Comment: No changes on hover... Don't know if you have any idea

Comment: @LuisGil, Please put this css in style.css file `.pif-has-gallery:hover .wp-post-image {
    opacity: 1!important;
}`

Comment: It's perfect now.

Comment: @LuisGil,  glad it helped you :).